# cannot manipulate a handlebars template after I insert it

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js

This is probably a noob question but:

I built a quiz, and then decided to load all my questions with handlebars templates, the problem is that after the template is inserted in place, i cannot manipulate the dom with jquery or anything else. Here is my Handlebars function:

```
mQ.loadQuestion = function () {
    "use strict";
    Handlebars.registerHelper("fill", function (data, options) {
        return options.fn(data[mQ.counter]);
    });
    $('#questions').remove();
    $('#answersFrame').remove();
    var templateScript = $('#fillQuestions').html(),
        theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(templateScript);
    $.getJSON("quiz.json", function (quiz) {
    $('#next').before(theTemplate(quiz));
    });
};
```

Okay I change the question with this function, the questions change fine, the quiz works fine, but after the new html template is inserted, it is as if all its classes and id's disappear, for example after I call the handlebars function and try to manipulate the dom, nothing happens. For example:

```
mQ.loadQuestion();
    $('.choices').show('slow');
```

Here the "choices" is a  classname within that html template, but after I call the Handlebars function, I cannot select and manipulate the new loaded html anymore, i.e. if the display of the choices were none, I cannot show them slowly, or if I wanna select an input radio, I cannot do it, it is as if the dom stops working after the template is loaded. For example, if the template loads empty radio buttons, and I want to select one of them after the template loads, I cannot do it. Hope I made my question clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One implemented into the DOM, handlebar template HTML is treated like any other HTML and is editable.

It is difficult to get a precise answer without an example. However, your template is injected AFTER a getJSON call. That is a AJAX call (asynchronous), so if you immediately query for ".choices", it won't find it in the DOM because the AJAX call hasn't been completed and the Handlebars template hasn't been injected. Try putting the fadeIn call within the AJAX callback, for example:

```
mQ.loadQuestion = function () {
    "use strict";
    Handlebars.registerHelper("fill", function (data, options) {
        return options.fn(data[mQ.counter]);
    });
    $('#questions').remove();
    $('#answersFrame').remove();
    var templateScript = $('#fillQuestions').html(),
        theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(templateScript);
    $.getJSON("quiz.json", function (quiz) {
        //JSON Callback. Will call this function and the run the code
        //Below once the JSON is available.
        $('#next').before(theTemplate(quiz));
        $('.choices').show('slow');
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you this works, however, it also works for example if I put an alert before trying to edit anything, I guess then there is time for the ajax call to complete, but my question is, you say the ajaxs call is not completed, but the template still correctly uses the json object and puts the correct keys in the correct place, how can it do that without the ajax call being completed?

Comment: An alert halts the code, and allows time for the AJAX call to complete. The template works because the template is render inside the getJSON callback, so at that point the data is available. Remember, an AJAX call is like loading another page; webpages don't load instantly, neither do AJAX calls. The Javascript will not wait for an AJAX call to complete before proceeding, this is why you must use callbacks.